# Display picture library slideshow from one subsite to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library

In SharePoint Online/M365, is it possible to create a picture slide show where the photo gallery is located on another subsite?  I'm also still using **classic** experience if this makes any difference. Unfortunately, we are not moving to **modern** yet.

We have photo galleries that are located on a different subsites and want to display them on other sub sites.

I can probably use Page Viewer web part but hoping there is another way.

Comment: You can use REST API call to get information of pictures & create slider. You can place this code to your subsite via CEWP

Comment: @Hardik, I already attempted this but still couldn't figure out how the slider moves to the next or previous image. REST API was able to identify the number of images in the gallery and display the first image correctly -- the issue is sliding it to the next or previous image. I have to do more research unless you have a solution ready I could refer to?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options in SP online on this
1. Using Image Gallery web part

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd

2. Highlighted content webpart has a carousel layout.
   Also SharePoint responsive carousel webpart using SPFx

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/

There are also some SPFx WebParts over there you could take a look at:

- https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/sharepoint-framework-slide-swiper
- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/bootstrap-slider
- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/jquery-photopile

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first link sounds good but it says its only for **modern pages** -- we are still using **classic** and not going to change to modern anytime soon, unfortunately.  I'll check out the other links.  Thanks.